# Why doesn't jslint like the use of call() on a function expression?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm getting this error.

```
Unexpected '.'.
```

for this line:

```
}).call(this);
```

I checked [jslinterrors.com](http://jslinterrors.com/) and could not find a reason.

Reproduce the error using:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var a = 1;
    a = a + 1;
}).call(this);
```

Comment: And what does the function look like ?

Comment: Most likely the source of the error is on one of the lines before the one that is raising the error. Take a look at the previous lines too.

Comment: I've added in a snippet to the question to reproduce the error, just copy  past in into jslint.com

Comment: IMO jslint is a counter-productive masochist tool. Have you tried jshint instead? It is a little less biased and much more configurable, though it also throws some false positives in some corner cases.

Comment: crockford wrote it, and he is a well respected javascript authority, who has published books on JavaScript.

Comment: *sigh* fair enough, if you want to follow a single man's biased view it is not our problem. JSHint was created and is maintained by a huge community of professional developers, whom care about code quality and not just a man's bias. Also, remember that static code analysis tools such as these are never 100% accurate, they serve mainly as training wheels for beginner developers.

Comment: I'm not following anyone, the question asks for a reason for the error.  I'm sure there is a reason, whether that reason is correct or not is not my concern.

Comment: Well yeah, I didn't downvote your question because it is quite clear. Reading through the other comments in the answer, it is clear that you know that your syntax is perfectly valid, so the question actually is "Why does this script written by Crockford does not like the string of characters I'm inputting into it?" which I can't really answer, but I'd assume lack of maintenance. That or personal bias. Crockford is very well known for his involvement in the JS language development,books and talks, but is also know for not drawing a line between his personal preference and actual bad practices.

Comment: Sorry if any of this comes through a bit rude, you can't read tones in the internet and I'm a bit too sleepy to word things better than this. Even though I couldn't help solving your issue, I'd still like to leave the suggestion to try JSHint. It is not only very well documented and maintained, it would surely improve your productivity by not forcing you to hunt error descriptions from your static code analysis tool in the dark corners of the internet (not so often, at least). `:)`

Comment: I'm not sure its personal bias, or just a desire to make JavaScript development more normalized as there are too many ways to do the same thing.  Engineers/CS majors in general have a hard time differentiating between technical correctness and technical preference.  Crockford is no different.  I also think he just likes to be weird to mess with people.  For example calling out `++` as an issue. I'm not sure he really believes this.  I'll check out jshint.com, but last I checked it was not as rigorous as jslint.com

Comment: http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/ turn on all enforcing rules and turn off all relaxing rules, it will be very rigorous. `=]` JSHint is moving away from coding style checks though, it cares most about syntax. And yes, I guess being a bit skeptical/eccentric is part of developers' personality stereotype after all.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your using an anonymous function which is an anti pattern in this way. The following should work:

```
(function () {}())
```

Comment: That's called an IIFE ( Immediately Invoked Function Expression ).  You are still using an anonymous function.  Why do you think an anonymous function is a an anti-pattern?

Comment: It is used in underscore a very popular library - see it here - http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html

Comment: jslint will complain about the end parenthesis like that, and will suggest `(function {}())`

Comment: Xotic is correct on code - was my error - anonymous function isn't antipattern but using call on a anonymous function with this in strict mode can lead to undefined because it can expose global object. You can cancel this behaviour as described here; http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#validthis. More on 'this' here; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#.22Securing.22_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with with the code that you supplied. Perhaps there is something not right in the parsing that jslint performs, or maybe there is a real reason for the warning, I can't find one. With a little dancing you can be off with the warning, by writing it like this.

```
/*global console */
(function () {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        var a = 1;
        a = a + 1;
        console.log(this);
    };
}()).call([]); // used array rather than this so that it is easy to see in console
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/sK4tw/)

Answer (score -2):

Functions wrapped in parenthesis are meant to be invoked immediately so you cannot use `.call()` there.

Example of function use

```
(function () {
    // do something
})();
```

Instead you could do

```
var foo = function () {
    // do something
};

foo.call(this); // within scope
```

Comment: They can be, they are not meant to be, many popular libraries use call on a function expression and it works fine.  The question is asking for the reason that jslint calls it out.

Comment: Just because they can be, doesn't mean they are meant to be.

Comment: `.call()` is a form to immediately invoke it, by the way.

Comment: The second method would not be useful if you are trying avoid polluting the namespace.